# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to make a client-server model, being new to python network programming I am stuck on an error which states the following:-

> tcpCliSoc.send('[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data))   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Here is the Server and client implementation

**TCP server implementation**

```
from socket import *  
from time import ctime

HOST = ''  
PORT = 21572  
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)  
BUFFSIZE = 1024  

tcpSerSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

tcpSerSoc.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSoc.listen(5)

while True:  
    print("waiting for connection......")  
    tcpCliSoc, addr = tcpSerSoc.accept()  
    print("connected from", addr)  

    while True:  
        data = tcpCliSoc.recv(BUFFSIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpCliSoc.send('[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data))
    tcpCliSoc.close()
tcpSerSoc.close()
```

**TCP client implementation**

```
from socket import *

__author__ = 'Lamer'

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21572
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFFSIZE = 1024

tcpCliSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSoc.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = input('>')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpCliSoc.send(data.encode())
    data = tcpCliSoc.recv(BUFFSIZE)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data.decode(encoding='utf-8'))

tcpCliSoc.close()
```

Comment: As an aside, you should use `sock.sendall()` over `sock.send()` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string interpolation is creating a string, not a bytes object:

```
>>> '%s foo' % b'bar'
"b'bar' foo"
```

(Notice that the result is of type `str` -- And it has a `'b'` and some quotes inserted in it that you probably don't want).

You probably want to interpolate bytes with bytes:

```
>>> b'%s foo' % b'bar'
b'bar foo'
```

Or, in your code:

```
tcpCliSoc.send(b'[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
tcpCliSoc.send('[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data))
```

the parameter `'[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data)` is a string, not a byte array. Even though you are using a bytes object for the second string placeholder, the overall formatted string "[blah] blah" is a string. You should be able to fix this fairly easily with something like:

```
message_str = '[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf_8'), data)
message_bytes = message_str.encode(utf-8)
tcpCliSoc.send(message_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.5.1 and faced the issue with sending and receiving data.
I solved the error "TypeError: string argument without an encoding" by adding   encoding to both server and client.

```
# Server Code:
while True:
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break;
    print("from connected user:"+ str(data))
    data = str(data).upper()
    print("Sending :"+ str(data))
    byte_message = data.encode()
    c.send(byte_message)
c.close()
```

```
# Client Code:
while(message != 'q'):
    fmessage = message.encode()
    s.send(fmessage)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("Recieved from server :" + str(data))
    message = input()
s.close()
```

Enjoy !!!

Dharmendra