# How can I solve TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'?

Tags: python

I have this programm, but it says to me the error on the title, I think I have to put something for apply utf-8, but I don't know where or how

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

status = 0

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
mySocket.bind(('localhost', 1234))



mySocket.listen(5)

while True:
    print('Waiting for connections')
    (recvSocket, address) = mySocket.accept()
    print('HTTP request received:')
    print(recvSocket.recv(1024))
    request = recvSocket.recv(1024)

    slot = request.split(' ')

    try:
        num = int(slot[1][1:])
    except ValueError:
        msg = ("Asegurese que su URL contiene un numero al final. Ejemplo: localhost:1234/56")
        recvSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + "<html><body>" + msg + "</body></html>" + "\r\n")
        status = 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777639/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score 1):

`send` expects `bytes`, not `string`. Strings in Python 3 are unicode, you have to specify how the string should be converted to bytes. Use something like `socket.send("some string".encode("utf-8"))` to convert string to `bytes` first.